# ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Tags: magento-1.9, error, system.log

Magento 1.9.2.3
Extension Causing error: Ameex Admin Activity Logger (Commerce Bees)
Error in system.log - over and over again

> Full error: ERR (3): Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0  in
>   /MyServerInfo/public_html/app/code/community/Ameex/Adminlog/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 27

Code from line 27 of Observer.php:

```
$currentId = $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]);
```

Full section of code that seems related to this error:

```
$adminlog = Mage::getModel('adminlog/adminlog');
        $dynamicValues = $this->_getDynamicValues($controllerName);
        $currentId = $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]);
        $storeId =  $request->getParam('store');
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
```

Otherwise the extension seems to work fine, but I would like to stop this error occurring. First of all because I'm not sure what it could be doing that I don't see and because it's filling up my system.log file and I don't like errors.
I contacted Extension creator, but there has been no response in several weeks.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you also add this function `_getDynamicValues($controllerName)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an error, it is just a notice, you can ignore it.

Otherwise fix it in this way:

```
$currentId = count($dynamicValues) ? $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]) : null;
```

Also try:

```
$currentId = isset($dynamicValues[0]) ? $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]) : null;
```

You can also suppress notices in PHP by changing the `error_reporting` php ini value.

You probably have `E_ALL`. You can safely change it to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`.

Comment: I haven't tried changing the error_reporting settings yet, but I tried the line of code you gave and nothing changed. Maybe I didn't understand what to do correctly? I simply went into the Observer.php file and took the line: 
$currentId = $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]); 
and replaced it with: 
$currentId = count($dynamicValues) ? $request->getParam($dynamicValues[0]) : null; 
but I am still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Also try isset($dynamicValues[0]) instead of count($dynamicValues)

Comment: That stopped it. Not sure exactly what I did, but it works for now. I'll have to do some research and learn more about it, but thanks. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Nothing special, it was just complaining because you where looking for something not exisiting. My code just said that if it does not exists you can cosider it as a null value. If it works for you pls accept the answer.

Comment: I thought I had already. I hit the UP button next to the answer